# Get phone number of iPhone that connected to car via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, car-integration

My car was stolen. But when the police found it and got it back, we noticed someone connected their iPhone to the car Bluetooth.

Does the car store that person's phone number, and can the phone number be retrieved to pass along to the police?

Answer (score 2):

If they allowed it to on their phone, it may have synced their contact list to the car stereo's memory, which could include their own phone number. Usually when you connect to a car's bluetooth system for the first time, there will be a popup asking for permission, similar to:

[image: screenshot of popup saying "Allow Contacts and Favorites Sync?"]

(I found this example [here](https://www.f150forum.com/f118/contacts-iphone-will-not-sync-properly-f-150-a-400143/#&gid=1&pid=1))